# Organizing layout with ids inside <include/> tag

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, include

I want to align below, left, right, top, bottom some elements of my layout A according to the things inside layout B.

So, I have:

Layout A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/stateview_coinshop"
style="@style/AlertPopup"
android:layout_width="@dimen/PopupWidth"
android:layout_height="@dimen/PopupHeight"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:clickable="false"
android:gravity="center" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/popup_window"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/PopupWidth"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/PopupHeight"
    layout="@layout/layoutB" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageBoxTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/popup_background"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/popup_background"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/popup_background"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="#152E08"
    android:shadowDx="-3"
    android:shadowDy="3"
    android:shadowRadius="2"
    android:text="Mytitle"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="italic|bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popup_window"
android:layout_width="@dimen/PopupWidth"
android:layout_height="@dimen/PopupHeight"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center" >

<!-- BORDER -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/popup_background"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/backgroundContainer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/backgroundContainer"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/backgroundContainer"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/backgroundContainer"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/PopupBorderUpDownMargin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/PopupBorderSideMargin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PopupBorderSideMargin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/PopupBorderUpDownMargin"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/pop_up_main_stroke"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

<!-- CLOSE BUTTON -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/PopupCloseButtonMargin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/PopupCloseButtonMargin"
    android:background="@drawable/pop_up_close_button"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:minWidth="48dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

THE PROBLEM: Layout A finds the ID's from B but they are being ignored. Even if I add them in layout B(the included one) as +id, as a value (id), id, anything. It does not work.

What can I do?

**EDIT:**
I solved this by modifying my layout's B root tag from RelativeLayout to merge. Simple change.